# Update 5 tables at once. Same columns

Tags: mysql, join, updates

The situation:

Update 5 tables (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5) at once. 
All tables have the column “title_galery” and “uid_galery”.
I need update all  “title_galery” columns to “New Title” where “uid_galery” are “555”.

Ps: the columns can be empty or with another data, so, I need only update the lines that match the “uid_galery”.

I have tried JOIN and INNER JOIN without sucess.

UPDATE

LAST ATTEMPT:

```
$conecta_for_003 = "UPDATE";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  table1";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.uid_galery=table1.uid_galery";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.uid_galery=table1.uid_galery";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.uid_galery=table1.uid_galery";

$conecta_for_003 .= " SET";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  table1.title_galery='New Title'";
$conecta_for_003 .= ", table2.title_galery='New Title'";
$conecta_for_003 .= ", table3.title_galery='New Title'";
$conecta_for_003 .= ", table4.title_galery='New Title'";
$conecta_for_003 .= " WHERE";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  table1.uid_galery='555'";
```

Comment: What *language* are you trying to do this in? SQL Server? MySQL? And what have you tried so far? StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: The language: MySQL.

Comment: The post was updated.

Answer (score 0):

This attempt works BUT ONLY for 2 tables.

```
$conecta_for_003 = "UPDATE";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  table1";
$conecta_for_003 .= ", table2";
$conecta_for_003 .= " SET";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  table1.title_galery='New Title'";
$conecta_for_003 .= ", table2.title_galery='New Title'";
$conecta_for_003 .= " WHERE";
$conecta_for_003 .= " table2.uid_galery = table1.uid_galery";
$conecta_for_003 .= " AND";
$conecta_for_003 .= "  table1.uid_galery='555'";
```

I tried to change it but no attempt worked.